# русский язык в jomSocial

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3

Как включить русский язык в jomSocial 4.2, Joomla 3.7.4 Stable .
установил язык(jomsocial rus frontend), ничего не помогает, кто знает плиз помогите

Comment: какой мультиязычный плагин  установлен ? Falang ?

Comment: Ничего такакого не установлено, мне нужен только один язык - русский, спасибо

Comment: а по дефолту какой язык установлен в Language manager ?

Comment: русский.........

Comment: странно, вы изначально установили английскую версию Joomla и после установили русскую локализацию ?

Comment: при инсталяции выбрал русскую, но она не выбралась потом переустановил русский, сама система на руском кроме jomSocial

Comment: При простой установке языкового пакета, файлы локализации для JoomSocial не будут установлены. Вам надо,либо найти на офф сайте русскую локализацию и установить, или же самому перевести текст в файлах Language

Comment: так я ее установил, при дебаге выявил 2 ошибки и починил их, показывает что файлы локализации берутся из русского перевода в дибаге. 
но ничего не работает продолжает брать англискую версию

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63063/discussion-between-arsen-and-l-vadim).